# How can I upgrade to Autoconf 2.6.2 or higher on Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, autoconf

My environment is Mac OS X 10.6. I have installed Autoconfig using MacPorts:

```
sudo port -v selfupdate
sudo port install autoconf
```

But the autoconf installed is 2.6.1. 
My question is how can I upgrade it to 2.6.2?

The program I am trying to compile need autoconf 2.6.2

```
configure.ac:14: error: Autoconf version 2.62 or higher is required
/opt/local/share/aclocal-1.11/init.m4:110: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE is expanded from...
configure.ac:14: the top level
autom4te: /Developer/usr/bin/gm4 failed with exit status: 63
aclocal-1.11: autom4te failed with exit status: 63
make[1]: *** [libmpeg2] Error 63
```

Comment: If you are compiling from a properly built tarball, you do not need to have autoconf.

Answer (score 4):

I usually do not bother installing any of the autotools on the system, but install them in $HOME instead.  Just grab the autoconf tarball from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/, unpack it and run:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME
 make
 make install
```

Make sure $HOME/bin is in your PATH before the system dir, or uninstall autoconf from the system.